# Try statement not running as I expect

Tags: python, string, exception

I have three functions, the `readHeader` thet reads the header of the a txt file, `readExpertsFile` that reads the contents of the file and the `exceptionNH` function that compares the file name and header and raises an exception if the two are not compatible (e.g. if the date in the name is not the same as the header).
Here are the three functions and a txt example:

```
def readHeader(fileName):
    fileIn = open(fileName, "r")

    fileIn.readline()
    day = fileIn.readline().replace("\n", "")
    fileIn.readline()
    time = fileIn.readline().replace("\n", "")
    fileIn.readline()
    company = fileIn.readline().replace("\n", "")
    scope = fileIn.readline().replace(":", "").replace("\n", "")

    fileIn.close()

    return (day, time, company, scope)


def readFile(fileName):
    expertsList = []

    expertsList.append(readHeader(fileName))

    fileIn = open(fileName, "r")

    for line_counter in range(LNHEADER):
        fileIn.readline()

    fileInE.close()

    return expertsList


def exceptionNH(fileName):
    try:
        assert fileName[10:17] == readFile(fileName)[3][0].lower().replace(":", "")
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error in input file: inconsistent name and header in file", fileName,".")
        exit()

fileName = "file.txt"
exceptionNH("2018y03m28experts10h30.txt")
```

2018y03m28experts10h30.txt:

```
Day:
2018-03-28
Time:
10:30
Company:
XXX
Experts:
...
...
```

My problem here is that on the try statement I expect the assert "sees" the comparation as `True` and skip the except clause but this is not happening.
I suspect that the `.lower()` is not working but I can't understand why.
If you see other things that could be better feel free to share, as I'm a new at python and want to improve myself.

Comment: Don't use `assert` when you really just need an `if` statement. Assertions can be disabled at run time.

Comment: @chepner "Assertions can be disabled at run time"... I did not know this, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you print both `fileName[10:17]` and `readExpertsFile(fileName)[3][0].lower().replace(":", "")`? Then you'll see why they are different.

Comment: Also, there is no function called `readExpertsFile` in the code you've shown. Nor a variable called `fileNameExperts`.

Comment: @cheper I didn't understand what you've said, could you please explain more?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The code poster above is an excerpt of a bigger project and I've tried change the names instead of posting all code, so that function and variable have the old names. I'll change in a minute.

Comment: You wrote a lot of text and a lot of code, just to ask how come `fileName[10:17]` does not equal `readFile(fileName)[3][0].lower().replace(":", "")`, but you did not write (or check yourself) what these two sides of `==` equal to. BTW the question has nothing to do with `try`.

Comment: @usr2564301 Ok, sorry I'm new here and I don't understand much about the site, I'll post an answer in a minute.

Comment: @zvone I tried to explain well my problem without the text being too long so I've omitted somethings. About the title, I couldn't thinks of a short and better title. Next time I'll try to resume better my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error. I was thinking that when I want to get the first element from the first tuple inside a list, I would need to write `list[position of item][position of tuple]`, instead of it's inverse.

Following the mkrieger1's advice, I printed `fileName[10:17]` and `readFile(fileName)[3][0].lower().replace(":", "")`, the first was good but the second was not showing the third item of the first tuple (that's from `readHeader`) but the first item of the third tuple.
I've changed from `readFile(fileName)[3][0].lower().replace(":", "")` to `readFile(fileName)[0][3].lower().replace(":", "")` and it's working now, thank you for the help.